# jsfiddle says there is an error but it works? Trying to create a cookie reading function

Tags: javascript, function, cookies, jsfiddle, indexof

```
document.cookie = "happy=random stuff";
function readCookie(name) {
    var cookie,cname,i;
    cookie = document.cookie.split(";");
    cname = name;
    for (i=0; i<=cookie.length; i++) {
        var c = cookie[i];
        if (c.indexOf(cname) == 0) {
            alert(c.substring(cname.length,c.length));
            return c.substring(cname.length,c.length);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

readCookie("happy");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a2R3j/
It appears that this line is wrong:

```
if (c.indexOf(cname) == 0) {
```

it works perfectly. However jsfiddle says there is an error. Is there actually anything wrong?

EDIT FOR CLARITY: I want it to return the cookie's content by calling the function getCookie(name here)
another edit for clarity: 
Yusaf Code: [image: stuff]

Code with indexOf: [image: stuff]

Comment: What exactly do you expect that to do? *edit* oh OK that makes more sense :-)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'indexOf' of undefined` It is because `c` is not defined. `cookie[i]` does not exist.

Comment: Change `for (i=0; i<=cookie.length...` to `for (i=0; i<cookie.length;...` then it will work. http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/a2R3j/2/

Comment: Also you have to change `cname = cname;` to `cname = name;`

Comment: Why that choice of cookie name? Legit purpose, or do you just need to grow up?

Comment: well, in the case that I need to "grow up" what do you suggest I name it to?

Comment: when you return the string do you want it to begin with =  ??

Comment: no, i want just the content. Also @Derek, that doesn't seem to fix the problem, as in jsfiddle shows a red dot next to it after pressing JSHint. Do I actually need to listen to that? Or is it just a warning?

Comment: @bnynn You'll need Derek's and Pointy's solutions together: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YBhy5/1/). The spot appears because of `==` instead of `===`.

Comment: Ok. As long as the code works. Thanks for the quick help! This is an awesome community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### http://jsfiddle.net/6qLZe/

use `.split("=")[1]` rather than your substring method

```
document.cookie = "joker=batman";

function readCookie(cname) {
    var cookie_split = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (i = 0; i < cookie_split.length; i++) {
        var cookie_var = cookie_split[i].split("=")[0];
        if (cookie_var == cname) {
            return cookie_split[i].split("=")[1];
        }
    }
    return null
}

alert(readCookie("joker"));
```

Comment: Why is `split` better than using `indexOf`? I can't see any benefit in  it.

Comment: don't remeber saying it is better

Comment: This is actually the answer I was looking for! jsfiddle returns no errors. (if this screenshot helps [screenie of the code with indexOf](http://i.imgur.com/sZi5qwn.png) ) [Yusaf's code](http://i.imgur.com/JNSIr7R.png) I guess the only question I have is  why this happens. If they're equally effective then why would jsfiddle return an error on one of them?

Answer (score 0):

You have one cookie in document.cookie - so the length is one, and that cookie is at position 0 (js is zero-based).

Your `for` loop goes as high as `i <= cookie.length`, so it iterates twice - first for `cookie[0]`, then for `cookie[1]`, where it fails because `cookie[1]` doesn't exist.

Change your `for` loop to `for (i = 0; i < cookie.length; i++) {`

Comment: @bnynn this doesn't work as you want, check my answer for your desired solution

Comment: I didn't say using split is better, i said it doesn't return a value he desires, i aksed him "when you return the string do you want it to begin with = ?" and his response was "no, i want just the content." however all you're solution does is fix the loop issue

Comment: Nonetheless, the original question was regarding the loop error - which this code fixes. If someone with a similar problem finds this question, it will work for them too.

Comment: Numpty? I think you should read the etiquette guidelines - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette

Comment: seriously? numpty? it's silly i meant it to show there were no hard feeling or anything, maybe some people can't take very small things

Comment: i think you also might have missed the part `Bring your sense of humor.`